# Getting servlet exception in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

trying to learn spring from this link :

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

but getting following error:

```
    type Exception report

    message Servlet execution threw an exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

   javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Getting above error repeating multiple times on browser and eclipse console.

[image: The dir structure is]

The file contents are : 
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


        <context:component-scan
            base-package="siso.springrolls.controller" />

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

Controller is :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/StartPage")
    public ModelAndView springContoller(){
        String message = "Hey welcome to Spring 3.0!! ";
        System.out.println("in controller");
        return new ModelAndView("StartPage","message",message);
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
</head>
<body>
<a href="StartPage.html">Click here </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error message in the server logs?

Comment: There should be a nested exception somewhere or another error in another logfile (maybe in tomcat's catalina.out?). Can you find it? Because the exception that you've pasted doesn't give any detail about your application.

Comment: C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\logs folder is empty. I am getting this error on browser(& eclipse console) while redirecting on click of "Click here"

Comment: Find out where the server logs are at. Maybe you run this directly from your IDE? Check the logs on the IDE.

Comment: Somewhere in the logs:
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)

Comment: I tried upgrading tomcat version to 7 and eclipse to Indigo, but exactly same error, one thing for sure its not an environment problem

Comment: one more important observation, "in controller" is getting printed on eclipse console multiple times before throwing above exception. I don't know why multiple threads are getting created?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to mix up of spring jars . I had the same problem .removed some jars from pom.xml and it worked .
Here is my original pom.xml . Basic Project using Spring 4 Hibernate 4

```
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Removed this below dependency and it worked fine

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Updated Answer : -

Add URL Mapping :

```
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

This should do the job .

Answer (score 0):

5 Hours wasted :(

Can anybody please tell me why the below code not working :

```
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
```

but if I change it to :

```
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

it worked fine. The directory structure after modification is :

[image]

Why it is not picking up html file and throwing 
**No mapping found for HTTP request with URI… in DispatcherServlet** and working file with JSP.

Answer (score 0):

try  to update that part of code and try

```
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>

 //Use this 
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

That is not correct
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

 </servlet-mapping>
```

**Updated**

try adding this too

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Getting below error with /*: 
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRolls/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
With '/', its working fine with StartPage.jsp